# Does Carathéodory's extension theorem still hold true if we only required that one measure be greater than the other?

Tags: measure-theory

The extension theorem states that if $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are $\sigma$-finite and they're equal on a generating set, then their extensions are equal everywhere. If we only required that $\lambda(A) \leq \mu(A)$ holds for every $A$ in their generating sets, could we still conclude that $\lambda(A) \leq \mu(A)$ holds for every $A$ of the extension of the generating set?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you assume the generating set to be a semi-ring, i. e. containing the empty set, closed under intersection, and for two sets in the generator, the difference is a finite disjoint union of sets of the generator.

Then their extension on the generated ring, fulfill $\lambda \leq \mu$ and therefore, the extended measures on the sigma algebra, which are the outer measures, have the same property by definition of the outer measure.